# How to select a particular pattern of words

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to identify words, `notes to financial statements`. In some cases, a sentence starts with `'notes to financial Statements'`, in other cases, it starts with `'   notes to financial statements'` (that is, there are some spaces before the words). I'd like to select 'notes to financial statements' only in these two cases, that is, a sentence that contains the words starts with or without some spaces. This is an easy job and I know I just need to use regular expression. The problem is there are other cases where some characters come before the words. For example, 'accompanying notes to financial statements'. So, the pattern is some words, one space, then notes to financial statements. I don't want to select this one.

Given a text as follows:

```
"""Take a look at accompanying notes to financial statements"""

n1=re.sub(r'\W*notes to financial statements','### Notes ###',text2)
```

The above command selects 'notes to financial statements', which I don't want to select because it is preceded by some words. This commands provides the output as follows:

```
"""Take a look at accompanying ### Notes ###"""
```

I think it is because `\W*` captures the one space between accompanying and notes. How can I make the command to not select in this case 'notes to financial statements' Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the `^` character, which matches the start of a line, and use `\s` instead of `\W` to match whitespace:

```
"""Take a look at accompanying notes to financial statements"""

n1=re.sub(r'^\s*notes to financial statements','### Notes
```

This will only match if the optional spaces and specified phrase are the first thing(s) on the line.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nY2cE9/1)

Note that you may want to consider adding the case-insensitive flag (`i`), as I suspect you will usually see a capital `N`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried to put ^, but it didn't capture notes to financial statements preceded by some spaces. When I removed ^, but keeps \s*, it captures that. I guess ^ doesn't work somehow. Anyway, so far, the one that works best is re.sub(r'\W\snotes to financial statements','### Notes ###', text)

Comment: @JimmyAhn That doesn't make sense. `^\s*` will definitely capture spaces at the start of the string. If you are dealing with it being at the star of a line that isn't the start of the string, use the `m` flag.